# jquery How to trigger click of links with same class but different text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger the click event of a link in my table.
Each link has the same class, but different values/text.

Take for example an employee table with two columns for the ID and Name.
The first column contains the link for each employee ID.
When a link is clicked, it will show an alert box showing the same ID.

Say I have a textbox, where user will input Emp ID. By clicking a button, the click event of the link with the same Emp ID in the table shall be triggered.

NOTE: My web app does more than this. I just need a way on how I can trigger the click event of each link and get its corresponding text.

```js
$(".lnkid").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).text();
  alert("Emp. ID: " + id);
});

$("#btntriggerlink").on("click", function() {
  var trigger_id = $("#txtid").val();
  //code to trigger click event goes here
});
```

```css
.lnk-ref {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1001</a></td>
        <td>Maria Rose</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1002</a></td>
        <td>Adler Brown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1003</a></td>
        <td>Sonjia Dean</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <br> Input Employee Number: <input type="text" id="txtid" />
  <button id="btntriggerlink">Trigger Link Event</button>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhonleonardo/xpvt214o/928936/) for this
Thanks in advance for whatever help I can get. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. Firstly, the class on the `a` elements is `lnkid`, not `linkid`. Secondly, `eq()` is used to select an element by its index, whereas you want to select it by its text. To do that you can use `filter()`, like this:

```js
$(".lnkid").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).text();
  alert("Emp. ID: " + id);
});

$("#btntriggerlink").on("click", function() {
  var trigger_id = $("#txtid").val().trim();
  $(".lnkid").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == trigger_id;
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.lnk-ref {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1001</a></td>
        <td>Maria Rose</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1002</a></td>
        <td>Adler Brown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a class='lnkid lnk-ref'>1003</a></td>
        <td>Sonjia Dean</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <br> Input Employee Number: <input type="text" id="txtid" />
  <button id="btntriggerlink">Trigger Link Event</button>
</div>
```

An alternative to `filter()` is `:contains`, but note that the latter will hit on any element which contains the text in any location, eg: `Foo 1001 bar`. `filter()` requires an exact match.

Comment: oops, yup, i missed on one lnkid selector. anyhow, this works! thank you so much!